# How to do an action when a variable hits a specific number javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

So basically I have done this code down bellow and I am trying to have a button that adds 1 to a variable and when that variable hits the specific number it plays an action. My final goal is to make it so when the variable hits the specific number it redirects to another page. I have tried for way too long and my friends don't know the solution either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head> </head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title> click tester </title>
<Meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<script> 
 var theClicks = 1;

 const win = 25;
        
 if(theClicks >= win) {
 alert('over 25'); 
 } 

</script>

<button onclick=theClicks++;>Button that adds1 to variable</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you need to call a function and do the check. You only do the check when the page is rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button onclick=theClicks++;>Button that adds1 to variable</button>
```

Just increments the variable. To expand that you could add more actions in the button onclick event, but it's much better to just put it all in a function you can call.

```
<script>
 var theClicks = 1;
 const win = 25;
 function doThing() {
    if (++theClicks >= win) {
       alert('over 25'); 
    } 
}
</script>
<button onclick='doThing()'>Button that adds1 to variable</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an approach like below. Basically create a function that keeps track of a counter variable (i.e., `i`). Next add a `click` event listener to the button and increment the counter on each click. When the counter reaches 25 then do some action (I made it only needed to be clicked 3 times in the code below for demo convenience) .

For example:

```js
// Reference to the DOM elements
const countEl = document.querySelector('#count-el');
const buttonEl = document.querySelector('button');

// Init a counter variable and return a function that increments it
const increment = (() => {
  let i = 1;

  return () => i++;
})();

// The click event listener
buttonEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Increment the count and update the UI if current click count is 3
  if (increment() === 3) {
    countEl.textContent = 'Do action now!';
  }
});
```

```html
<span id="count-el"></span>
<br />
<button>Click 3 times to do action</button>
```